# Reusable custom sort

Tags: powershell

I find myself working with a lot of DNS data recently and I've been using a custom sort expression to sort FQDNs by each dotted piece of the name in reverse so that records in the same zone/subzone sort next to each other. For example:

```bsh
# Build some fake data that normally comes from API call results
# There are generally more columns in the results and they're not always the same
$fqdns = @'
"fqdn","otherdata"
"a.example.com","foo"
"a.example.org","foo"
"example.com","foo"
"example.org","foo"
"www.example.com","foo"
"www.example.org","foo"
"www.sub.example.com","foo"
"www.sub.example.org","foo"
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$fqdns | sort @{E={$a=$_.fqdn.Split('.'); [array]::Reverse($a); $a -join '.'}}
```

The sort expression works great, but it's a lot to type when working interactively in the shell. I'm trying to figure out how I can add it as a variable or function to my profile so that I can re-use it with less typing. The kicker is that the string property that I'm doing the initial Split on won't always be called `fqdn`. So I'd need something where I can still specify that value. I envision being able to type something like this:

```bsh
$fqdns | sort (fqdnsort fqdn)
```

*P.S. I'm not necessarily looking for efficiency improvements in the expression itself, but if you have ideas those are welcome as well.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The custom ranking behavior you affect is completely contained in the argument you pass to `sort`/`Sort-Object` - so all you have to do is write a function that returns such an object:

```
function Get-FqdnSortKey
{
    return @{E={$a=$_.fqdn.Split('.'); [array]::Reverse($a); $a -join '.'}}
}
```

Then use like:

```
$fqdns |Sort-Object (Get-FqdnSortKey)
```

Before making any other *functional* modifications, let's refactor and re-format the existing code slightly for clarity:

```
function Get-FqdnSortKey
{
  param()

  $SortKeyExpression = {
    $a=$_.fqdn.Split('.')
    [array]::Reverse($a)
    $a -join '.'
  }

  return @{Expression=$SortKeyExpression}
}
```

If you want to parameterize the name of the source property inside the property expression, you'll have to close over the function parameter value(s) with `GetNewClosure()`:

```
function Get-FqdnSortKey
{
  param(
    [string]$PropertyName = 'Fqdn'
  )

  $SortKeyExpression = {
    $a = $_.$PropertyName.Split('.')
    [array]::Reverse($a)
    $a -join '.'
  }.GetNewClosure()

  return @{Expression=$SortKeyExpression}
}
```

This way, when `$PropertyName` is resolved by the resulting closure at a *later point in time*, it will still have the value it had inside `Get-FqdnSortKey` when we defined it.

---

If you want to add *intrinsic* sorting behavior to your data, you can do so by defining a custom data type with PowerShell's `class` keyword - the only requirement for intrinsic sorting is that our type implements the `System.IComparable` interface:

```
class FqdnWithMetaData : IComparable
{
    [string]$Fqdn
    [string]$OtherData

    hidden [string] $_namespaceOrder = $null

    [int]
    CompareTo([object]$other)
    {
      if($other -isnot [FqdnWithMetaData]){
        throw [ArgumentException]::new('other')
      }

      return [string]::Compare($this.GetNamespaceOrder(), $other.GetNamespaceOrder(), [StringComparison]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    }

    hidden [string] GetNamespaceOrder()
    {
      if(-not $this._namespaceOrder){
        $labels = $this.Fqdn.Split('.')
        [array]::Reverse($labels)
        $this._namespaceOrder = $labels -join '.'
      }

      return $this._namespaceOrder
    }
}
```

Now that we've implemented `IComparable`, `Sort-Object` will just call `$current.CompareTo($next)` on the input as part of its comparison routine:

```
$data = @(
  [FqdnWithMetaData]@{ Fqdn = 'yahoo.com' },
  [FqdnWithMetaData]@{ Fqdn = 'google.com' },
  [FqdnWithMetaData]@{ Fqdn = 'google.net' },
  [FqdnWithMetaData]@{ Fqdn = 'amazon.com' }
)

$data |Sort-Object    # No need to supply anything else here

# Resulting in
Fqdn       OtherData
----       ---------
amazon.com
google.com
yahoo.com
google.net
```

See the [`about_Classes` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes) for more information on using custom data types in PowerShell

Comment: The function is exactly the type of thing I was going for. And while it works when the property name, `fqdn`, is hard coded, it stops working when I try to make that value a parameter in the function. I'll add an edit to show what I mean. I also love the idea of the custom type, but will it work when the shape of the data changes (more or less properties that may or may not have the same names)?

Comment: Ooh...I could also probably just make the custom type only apply to the FQDN string...similar to how you can better sort string IP addresses by casting them to `[version]` in an expression.

Comment: @RyanBolger I've updated the answer to show how you can parameterize the function correctly

Comment: Awesome! GetNewClosure() was the key and thanks for providing the additional explanation. I don't suppose you have time to provide an example of the IComparable class that I could apply directly to a string value like `[Fqdn]'example.com'` instead of the whole object?

Comment: Well, as soon as you cast a string to `[AnyOtherType]` it's no longer a string ^_^ if you add a constructor that only takes a single string argument (ie. `FqdnWithMetaData([string]$Fqdn)`), PowerShell's conversion logic would automatically pick that when explicitly casting a string value

Comment: The intent would be to use it within a sort expression like `@{E={[NamespaceSortableFqdn]$_.fqdn}}`.

Comment: If you want me to further explain `IComparable` with PowerShell classes, [here's an 80 minute recording of just that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zggWL-0gefo) from PSConfEU earlier this year :)

Comment: I'll see if I can figure it out after watching the video and perhaps post a separate question if I get stuck. Thanks again.

Comment: @RyanBolger Please note you don't have to spell out the surrounding hashtable literal, `$strings |Sort {[SortableFqdnType]$_}` will work just fine. But yeah, post another question if you hit a wall again :)